# JAVASCRIPT MongoDB delete specific object from array

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, express, ejs

I have got a nested array brought within a query from database, query brings the following:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("623rf3f22275f399f88bb"),
  first_name: 'Are',
  last_name: 'You',
  email: 'helping@stackoverflow.me',
  password: '$2a$10$BSmezAjYkqU.234t65sT1pPOhg5jxosYrFzwjqXM3On3v.b7p46K1WS',
  username: 'lcd1',
  Messages: [
    {
      msgcontent: 'The user whatever said: whatsup.'
    },
    {
      msgcontent: 'The user whatever said: whatsup.'
    },
    {
      msgcontent: 'The user whatever said: whatsup.'
    },
    {
      msgcontent: 'The user whatever said: whatsup.'
    },
    {
      msgcontent: 'The user whatever said: whatsup.'
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have a button for deleting in each of the brought iterations of a for loop on the page, how do I delete a specific message from the array using the button displayed from the iteration on the page?

I've got this displaying messages:

```
<% if (messages.length > 0) { %>
    <% for (let nr = 1; nr <= messages.length; nr++) { %>
        <div class="cardmsgpage">
        <div class="displaymsg">Message <%= [nr] %> : <%= messages[nr-1].msgcontent %>  </div>
        <div class="sideways">
        
        <form action="/deletemsg:id" method="POST">
            <button class="msgpagebtn" type="submit"><img class="icon" src="/images/trash-can-solid.svg"></button>
        </form>
        
        </div>
        </div>
    <% } %>
```

and on the POST method I have:

```
app.post('/deletemsg', function (req, res) {
    
        for (let nr = 0; nr <= messages.length; nr++) { 
            message = messages[nr];
             }
    
    users.findOne({}).then(result =>{
        console.log(result);
        users.deleteOne( { "Messages" : [messages[nr]]      } );
        console.log(result);
    })
});
```

Can anyone tell me how I can delete only the message matching the button of the iteration that displayed it?

Comment: Give the message an id and connect the button to the specific id.

Comment: How do I do that? Can you show me examples?

Comment: Do I do that server side or client side? Unsure how to give it an id

Comment: I am really lost here

Comment: `/deletemsg:id` in the action field of your form should be `/deletemsg/:id`. Then you can grab this `id` (while handling the post request) using `req.params.id`.

Comment: Right, so I have <form action="/deletemsg/:id" method="POST"> client side.. Then server side I need to add const id = req.params.id; ? And what does the params.id stand for? where is this id mentioned in the message for loop in ejs that is displayed? so that the matching message is what is deleted?

Comment: Please see the attached answer, and lemme know....

Comment: Just commented..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your concern correctly,

I think you are trying to say that you are displaying all the messages(as mentioned above in the problem) as `Message i : <message content>` and a delete button next to it, upon clicking which sends a `POST` request to the server to delete the message you've clicked on.

According to me, you can do one thing.....

When post request is made, it should be known to the handeler that which database record is to be modified(object id) and then inside of it which message is to be deleted.

To identify the message which should be deleted you can provide unique id to each of the message object inside your Messages property in database record or you can make a separate message schema and model and use it to store message in Messages array, then each message in Messages array will have unique id.

And then, we can use combination of the database record id(objectId) and the message id to delete the specific message from a specific database record.

**Each message having unique id looks like...**

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("623rf3f22275f399f88bb"),
  first_name: 'Are',
  last_name: 'You',
  email: 'helping@stackoverflow.me',
  password: '$2a$10$BSmezAjYkqU.234t65sT1pPOhg5jxosYrFzwjqXM3On3v.b7p46K1WS',
  username: 'lcd1',
  Messages: [
    {
      _id: <message-id>,
      msgcontent: 'The user whatever said: whatsup.'
    },
    {
      _id: <message-id>,
      msgcontent: 'The user whatever said: whatsup.'
    }
    ...........
  ]
}
```

Pass record's objectId and Messages array or whole object to the ejs file. Your action field of the form looks like `/deletemsg/:record_id/:msg_id`.

**Inside your ejs file**

```
// record_id is objectId of database record
<% if (messages.length > 0) { %>
    <% for (let nr = 1; nr <= messages.length; nr++) { %>
        <div class="cardmsgpage">
        <div class="displaymsg">Message <%= [nr] %> : <%= messages[nr-1].msgcontent %>  </div>
        <div class="sideways">
        
        <form action="/deletemsg/record_id/messages[nr-1]._id" method="POST">
            <button class="msgpagebtn" type="submit"><img class="icon" src="/images/trash-can-solid.svg"></button>
        </form>
        
        </div>
        </div>
    <% } %>
```

**Handle the `POST` request**

```
app.post('/deletemsg/:record_id/:msg_id', function (req, res) {
    users.findOne({_id: req.params.record_id }).then(result =>{
        
        if(result){
           console.log(result);
           let messages = result.Messages;

           // you have msg id, you have to delete that message
           let idxToDelete = messages.findIndex(msg=>{
                return msg._id === req.params.msg_id;
           });

           if(idxToDelete != -1)
              messages.splice(idxToDelete, 1);
           
           result.Messages = messages;
           result.save().then(()=>{
              console.log("Message deleted!!!");
           }).catch(err=>{
              console.log(err);
           });
        }
    })
});
```

That's it......

**Note:-** you will have message and record schema like this below.....

```
const msg_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    msgcontent: {type: String}
});
const record_schema = mongoose.Schema({
    // everything same ......
    // Messages array will have msg_schema types
    Messages: [msg_schema]
});
```

Comment: app.post('/deletemsg/:record_id/:msg_id', function (req, res) {
 
  for (let nr = 0; nr <= messages.length; nr++) { 
   message = messages[nr];
    }
 users.findOne({ _id: req.params.record_id }).then(result =>{
  console.log(result);
  users.deleteOne( { "Messages" : [msgcontent]} );
  console.log(result);
 })
});

I have this, and not working still, with:

    <form action="/deletemsg/record_id/messages[nr-1]._id"
     <button class="msgpagebtn" type="submit"><img class="icon" src="/images/trash-can-solid.svg"></button>
    </form>

Comment: I dont understand where this record id is coming from, no info matches, nothing is pointing for :record_id

Comment: I get you saying that "record_id is objectId of database record" but there isn't anything thats pointing one towards the other, query is coming back null on the users.findOne({_id: req.params.record_id })

Comment: I have a different build, I'm using Mongodb not mongoose, using schema in server code not as include, some parts of your example don't add up for me.. Either that or I'm yet too green in coding